# I've a fatal problem for install better-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, strapi, better-sqlite3

Node.js version is 18.14.1
npm version is 9.3.1
VS studio version is 2022 Community

When I wanted to build a Strapi project, the better-sqlite3 package couldn't be installed. I tried my best but it didn't work. Who can help me?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AtMD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLOXm.jpg)

Solve this problem!

Comment: May be the problem is come form CPU, my type of CPU is AMD